# Syntax for "addAll()" to list in grails?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

In java, if I have a list, I can use `addAll(otherList);` to add all the elements from one list to another.

What is the equivalent in grails? I have a Domain object with a hasMany relationship. To add to it, I would use something like

```
Object.addToMyList(someitem);
```

and it seems like

`Object.addAllToMyList(otherList)`

does not exist. 
What is the equivalent in grails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To clarify - by default the collection is a `Set`, but `addAll()` works with any `Collection`.

You can call `addAll()` and it'll work fine, although the back-references won't be set if it's bidirectional. This doesn't affect persistence, just the current in-memory state.

There's nothing built into GORM for this, so I suppose the "right" way is a loop, e.g.

```
otherItems.each { foo.addToBars(it) }
```

Comment: I've noticed that if validation fails on any of the addTo.. calls, then nothing gets saved, even if you handle the error, remove the item from foo, etc.  There's no no error when invoking foo.save() either. Particularly annoying if you have a large list of items to add that might happen to contain an item thats been previously added.