# Is there in grails something like domainClass.addToAll? for one to many or many to many

Tags: grails

do we have in gorm something like addAll method in groovy?, i mean something like

```
someDomainClass.addToAll***
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has a good answer here [Syntax for "addAll()" to list in grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326305/syntax-for-addall-to-list-in-grails).
I don't know why a addAllToEntity wouldn't exist, but it wouldn't do much more then the loop mentioned in the answers (the one you got and the one I suggested), would it?

Answer (score 2):

No we do not. But it is easy to work around:

```
[child1, child2, child3].each { parent.addToChildren it }
```

Comment: thanks, it easy but why could be the reason to do not have a method like that?